# Creating a Customer Refund record for a Customer Deposit associated with a Sales Order

Tags: netsuite

I'm getting close. I'm am getting hung up on adding the Customer Deposit to the Customer Refund. Here is the code I am using to create a Customer Refund.

```
var ifxCreateCustomerRefund = {
    fromSalesOrder: function () {
        var salesOrder = nlapiGetNewRecord();
        var customerRefund = nlapiCreateRecord('customerrefund');           

        customerRefund.setFieldValue("customer", salesOrder.getFieldValue("entity"));
        customerRefund.setFieldValue("paymentmethod", salesOrder.getFieldValue("custbody_ifx_cc_payment_method"));
        var account = ifxFindRecord.find("account", "number", "1099");
        customerRefund.setFieldValue("account", account.id);
        nlapiLogExecution("debug", "today", nlapiDateToString(nlapiStringToDate(this.today())));
        customerRefund.setFieldValue("trandate", nlapiDateToString(nlapiStringToDate(this.today())));

        nlapiLogExecution("debug", "order #", salesOrder.getFieldValue("tranid"));
        nlapiLogExecution("debug", "deposittransaction", JSON.stringify(salesOrder.getFieldValue("deposittransaction")));

        var deposits = nlapiSearchRecord("customerdeposit", null, new nlobjSearchFilter("createdfrom", null, "is", salesOrder.id), null);
        nlapiLogExecution("debug", "customer deposits", JSON.stringify(deposits));

        customerRefund.insertLineItem("deposit", 1);
        customerRefund.setLineItemValue("deposit", "doc", 1, deposits[0].id);
        customerRefund.setLineItemValue("deposit", "apply", 1, true);

        nlapiSubmitRecord(customerRefund);
    },
    today: function () {
        var dt = new Date();
        var str = (dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dt.getDay() + "/" + dt.getFullYear();
        return nlapiDateToString(nlapiStringToDate(str));
    }
};
```

It is giving me this error:

> You have attempted an invalid sublist or line item operation. You are
>   either trying to access a field on a non-existent line or you are
>   trying to add or remove lines from a static sublist.

Can you help me get the Customer Deposit associated with the Sales Order to be applied to the Customer Refund?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The customer refund needs to be initialized with the customer id and then the available deposits will already be present. Adapted from my previous answer:

```
var cr = nlapiCreateRecord('customerrefund',{entity:salesOrder.getFieldValue("entity")}); // id of customer
cr.setFieldValue('paymentmethod', salesOrder.getFieldValue("custbody_ifx_cc_payment_method"));
... // do your account assignment etc.

var deposits = nlapiSearchRecord("customerdeposit", null, new nlobjSearchFilter("createdfrom", null, "is", salesOrder.getId()), null);
 var depositId = deposits[0].getId();
 for(var i = cr.getLineItemCount('deposit'); i>0; i--){
    if(depositId == cr.getLineItemValue('deposit', 'doc', i)){
    cr.setLineItemValue('deposit', 'apply', i, 'T');  // need this for at least one line.
    break;
 }
nlapiSubmitRecord(cr);
```

Comment: Thanks @bknights, that was exactly what I was looking for